# How manipulate a dataframe to obtain data in column ad data in raw

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I start from the example here reported "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19664313/how-to-have-query-return-samples-of-row-values-as-columns"

Actually, I did not have problem to find a solution with other post, but not in this case.

I have the following database:

```
    | Name | Gene |
    |A     | gene1|
    |A     | gene2|  
    |A     | gene3| 
    |B     | gene1|
    |B     | gene2|
    |C     | gene1|
    |C     | gene3|
```

How can change my dataframe in:

```
    |Name | Gene1 | Gene2 | Gene3 | 
    |A    |gene1  | gene2 | gene3 |
    |B    |gene1  | gene2 | ----- |
    |C    |gene1  | ----- | gene3 |
```

Also obtaining a raw with data for each sample may useful.

Many thanks in advance

I tried to applied code reported in [How to have query return samples of row values as columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19664313/how-to-have-query-return-samples-of-row-values-as-columns) without success.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PIVOT](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select-pivot.html) function.

```
SELECT
        name,
        (CASE WHEN gene1 IS NULL THEN '-----' ELSE gene1 END) AS gene1,
        (CASE WHEN gene2 IS NULL THEN  '-----' ELSE gene2 END) AS gene2,
        (CASE WHEN gene3 IS NULL THEN '-----' ELSE gene3 END) AS gene3
    FROM table_name
    PIVOT ( 
        FIRST(gene) AS gene 
        FOR (gene) IN ('gene1' as gene1, 'gene2' as gene2, 'gene3' as gene3)
    );
```

```
+----+-----+-----+-----+
|name|gene1|gene2|gene3|
+----+-----+-----+-----+
|A   |gene1|gene2|gene3|
|B   |gene1|gene2|-----|
|C   |gene1|-----|gene3|
+----+-----+-----+-----+
```

OR

```
scala> df.printSchema
root
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- gene: string (nullable = true)
```

```
df
.groupBy("name")
.pivot("gene")
.agg(
     when(
         first("gene").isNotNull, 
         first("gene")
     ).otherwise("-----")
).show(false)

+----+-----+-----+-----+
|name|gene1|gene2|gene3|
+----+-----+-----+-----+
|A   |gene1|gene2|gene3|
|B   |gene1|gene2|-----|
|C   |gene1|-----|gene3|
+----+-----+-----+-----+
```