# SQL Server: mutiple records merge to a same row with the same ID

Tags: sql-server

I have a table look like this:

```
P_ID    Lang   
1001    EN
1001    German
```

Expecting result:

```
P_ID Lang1  Lang2  
1001  EN     German
```

Comment: same as this question, and it has the answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17076089/convert-row-data-to-column-in-sql-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *just* had to do a [PIVOT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) like this, so here is my code modified for your situation:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT P_ID,
           Lang,
           NumberedLang = 'Lang' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
               (PARTITION BY P_ID ORDER BY Lang) AS NVARCHAR(100))               
    FROM   YourTableName   
) AS OrderLangs
PIVOT (MAX(Lang) FOR NumberedLang IN (Lang1, Lang2)) AS PivotedLangs
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3be20/10) to show you that it works.

If you don't want to specify all of the different `NumberedLang` values then you will have to use 'dynamic' pivots where you do all of the code in text based SQL. They can be quite inefficient though due to no query plan available.

Comment: I only have 5 different languages for now, but it will be very useful to use dynamic pivots later on for the next stage. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit ugly, but you can do something like this:

```
select p_id
, max( case when langNum=1 then lang else null end ) as Lang1
, max( case when langNum=2 then lang else null end ) as Lang2
, max( case when langNum=3 then lang else null end ) as Lang3
, max( case when langNum=4 then lang else null end ) as Lang4
, max( case when langNum=5 then lang else null end ) as Lang5
-- ...
from ( 
    select p_id
      , lang
      -- Get a number for each row, starting from 1 for each p_id:
      , row_number() over ( partition by p_id order by lang ) as LangNum
    from theTable
) as x
group by p_id
```