# Advice on how to store data type - List<>, Dictionary, XML, Rows, or?

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, excel, entity-framework

I am designing a database table that will hold the column headers of many differently-formatted Excel files. I need to do this because I ultimately need to know the "format" of the Excel files that will be created dynamically upon the user needing certain reports.

I am wondering if there is a common practice/pattern on doing this, i.e. what format is best to essentially store a `Dictionary<key, value>` in a database? Maybe XML? Individual rows with a 2-column design (index, value)? Or how do I story a Dictionary or List in a database?

Say my Excel file looks like this:

```
|  FirstName  |  LastName  |  PhoneNo  |
```

I need to store the three cells, i.e. their corresponding index and value, e.g. `[0, "FirstName"], [1, "LastName"], [2, "PhoneNo"]`.

I am thinking this can be stored in my Business Object as a `List<int, string> ColumnHeaders`, but am not sure how best to store this in a database (`SQL Server`) since when working with List<> objects in the past, they usually correspond to rows in the database and it does not make sense (at the moment at least) to store all of these column headers in each row, i.e. something like this:

```
ID  |  ProjectID  |  ColIndex  |  ColValue  
1   |  32         |  0         |  FirstName
2   |  32         |  1         |  LastName
3   |  32         |  2         |  PhoneNo
4   |  54         |  0         |  Name
5   |  54         |  1         |  City
6   |  54         |  2         |  State
7   |  54         |  3         |  Country
```

Any suggestions/tips?

Comment: If you could do on sql side then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745042/efficiently-convert-rows-to-columns-in-sql-server?rq=1 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22454545/convert-columns-of-data-to-rows-of-data-in-sql-server?rq=1 might help

Comment: Sounds like you're wanting to parse an excel file and store it in a database. I would go the relational database route if that's your actual goal. Yes, it's a bit of work in setting up a table for a "project", a table for "columns", and a table for "rows", "cells" whatever but it's the right thing to do in the long run.

Comment: @ZAT: Thanks for the links, I'll take a look and get back.

Comment: @Atoms: Interesting aspect, would you mind elaborating a bit so I could grasp your design better? Thanks!